# uniq: printing all duplicated lines and repeat counts is NOT meaningless

Tags: linux, shell, duplicates, posix, uniq

Is there a way to show the duplicated counts **with** the actual duplicated lines **repeated**?

For example, input:

```
AAAA XXXX
AAAA YYYY
BBBB ZZZZ
```

Expected output:

```
2 AAAA XXXX
2 AAAA YYYY
1 BBBB ZZZZ
```

Using the Linux program `uniq`, it refuses to show the duplicated line `2 AAAA YYYY`.

Linux command used:

```
printf 'AAAA XXXX\nAAAA YYYY\nBBBB ZZZZ' | uniq --count --check-chars 4
      2 AAAA XXXX
      1 BBBB ZZZZ
```

The `-D` option in uniq means `print all duplicate lines`. But it says it is meaningless.

```
printf 'AAAA XXXX\nAAAA YYYY\nBBBB ZZZZ' | uniq --count -D --check-chars 4
uniq: printing all duplicated lines and repeat counts is meaningless
Try 'uniq --help' for more information.
```

In my actual use case, XXXX YYYY ZZZZ are the file paths, and AAAA BBBB are the md5 hashes of the file contents. If XXXX and YYYY hashes are identical, I need to check file XXXX and YYYY. However I cannot get the file path of YYYY.

Comment: I just find I may use `printf 'AAAA XXXX\nAAAA YYYY\nBBBB ZZZZ' | uniq -D --check-chars 4`. But I cannot get the number of repeated counts. I would like to sort by that count descending afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there's an easier method, but one potential option using awk:

```
printf 'AAAA XXXX\nAAAA YYYY\nBBBB ZZZZ' | awk '{a[$1]++; b[NR] = $1; c[NR] = $1 FS $2} END{for (i=1; i<=length(b); i++) {print a[b[i]], c[i]}}'
2 AAAA XXXX
2 AAAA YYYY
1 BBBB ZZZZ
```

Proper formatting:

```
printf 'AAAA XXXX\nAAAA YYYY\nBBBB ZZZZ' |\
awk '{
    a[$1]++
    b[NR] = $1
    c[NR] = $1 FS $2
}

END {
    for (i = 1; i <= length(b); i++) {
        print a[b[i]], c[i]
    }
}'
2 AAAA XXXX
2 AAAA YYYY
1 BBBB ZZZZ
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`join`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) to combine the `uniq` output with the original input.

```
$ join -1 1 -2 2 <( printf 'AAAA XXXX\nAAAA YYYY\nBBBB ZZZZ') <(printf 'AAAA XXXX\nAAAA YYYY\nBBBB ZZZZ' | uniq --count --check-chars 4) | cut -d' ' -f1-3
AAAA XXXX 2
AAAA YYYY 2
BBBB ZZZZ 1
```

Comment: Thank you. Nice solution which makes use of `join`. But my filenames may contain spaces also. Simply `cut` by space does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you put tab between the fields? `join` allows you to specify the field delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

With this little `awk` you might get something usable?

```bash
awk '
    { arr[$1] = arr[$1] FS $2 }
    END {
        for (md5 in arr) {
            n = split(arr[md5], paths)
            print md5, n
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                print "\t" paths[i]
        }
    }
'
```

```
BBBB 1
    ZZZZ
AAAA 2
    XXXX
    YYYY
```

Comment: Nice, but why not stick to the OPs output spec (mostly - we're still losing the ordering)? `for (md5 in arr) {
            n = split(arr[md5], paths)
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                print n, md5, paths[i]
        }`